# For loop runs twice the result?

Tags: android, sqlite, pos

I am new to Android. I am creating a native MobilePOS Android application for printng by using Bluetooth. This is my code:

```
private void showandadd() {
        /*String num="";
        num=num+String.valueOf(number);*/
        String string1="";
        String string2="";
        String string3="";


        if(num==""){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Wrong input!! try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(flag==1) {
            getItem(directadd);
            if(blankflag!=1) {
                int updatedPrice = Integer.parseInt(this.price);
                int data = Integer.parseInt(this.num);
                if(data==0){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Wrong input!! insert different quantity number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    int d = updatedPrice * data;
                    this.price = d + "";

                    // String str = itemName + "      \t" + num + " No" + "      \t" + "Rs " + price;
                    printdetailsnew.add(itemName);
                    quantitynum.add(num);
                    amount.add(price);
                    num = "";
                    directadd = "";
                    flag = 0;
                    blankflag = 0;
                }
            }
            num = "";
            directadd = "";
            flag = 0;
            blankflag = 0;

        }else {
            getItem(directadd);
            if(blankflag!=1) {
                //String str = itemName + "      \t" + num + " No" + "      \t" + "Rs " + price;
                printdetailsnew.add(itemName);
                quantitynum.add("1");
                amount.add(price);
                num = "";
            }
            directadd="";
            blankflag=0;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<printdetailsnew.size();i++){
            string1=string1+ printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t"+"\n";
            string2=string2 +"No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+"\n";
            string3= string3 + amount.get(i)+"\n";

            result = printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t" + "No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+ amount.get(i)+"\n";

            System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+result);


        }

        this.selection.setText(string1);
        this.selection2.setText(string2);
        this.selection3.setText(string3);
        num="";
    }
```

There are 3 strings assigned to result.
I am getting result twice when I am press second item.
when I am select first item getting "Itemname Quantity ampount" format like
Tea 1qty 10rs...when I enter second item output will came first item+first item+second item show like this:

```
Tea 1qty 10rs
Tea 1qty 10rs
Coffee 1qty 12rs
```

I want to get result

```
Tea 1qty 10rs
Coffee 1qty 12rs
```

like this...please any one can help me

Comment: Are you sure that data was not adding twice to list?

Comment: Your problem is that you are looping through **all** of the items you added each time you add a new item.  You want to make sure you only loop through **one** item per label.  At least that is what I understand from what you are trying to achieve.  Why do you have 3 strings and 3 labels? If you are making a POS system you would want to dynamically generate how many labels you create or just use 1 label and add in a new line each time you add a new item.  I can try to show you an example if you can confirm this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok..any sample examples are there.?

Comment: I am sending Printing Acivity result will be like above mentioned format

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be to use one label and append to it each time you add a new item.

Instead of this:

```
for(int i=0;i<printdetailsnew.size();i++){
        string1=string1+ printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t"+"\n";
        string2=string2 +"No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+"\n";
        string3= string3 + amount.get(i)+"\n";

        result = printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t" + "No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+ amount.get(i)+"\n";

        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+result);


    }

    this.selection.setText(string1);
    this.selection2.setText(string2);
    this.selection3.setText(string3);
    num="";
```

Change it to this:

```
str = this.selection.getText().toString();
str += printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t" + "No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+ amount.get(i)+"\n";

this.selection.setText(str);
num="";
```

Comment: This can be use inside for loop or outside for loop...?

Comment: You would not need the for loop, as I understand your method is called every time the item is added.  This code will automatically take the previous string with the current items on there and append to it.

Comment: Ok..but how can i parse the str this activity to print activity...  One thing you told no need for loop..hoe can i get(i)...?

Comment: Ok..but how can i parse the str this activity to print activity...  One thing you told no need for loop..hoe can i get(i)...?str += printdetailsnew.get(i)+"\t" + "No."+ quantitynum.get(i)+"\t"+ amount.get(i)+"\n";

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do.  However, if you are trying to make a method to add items to a POS basket, then you should not need a loop for that.  Normally, you would create an array and store all the POS items in there (you can make it multidimensional to store stuff like price with the names).  Then when you add an item your method will simply append that list and then it can either append the GUI label or run a loop through the entire array to fully redraw the label.